# Why is `terraform init -backend-config` not reading my backend config file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to run `terraform init` and point to a specific backend config.

Reading the documentation on Terraform, it is just a standard key=value file, just like a tfvars. This is what my config file looks like :

```
resource_group_name  = "MY_RG_NAME"
storage_account_name = "MY_SA_NAME"
container_name       = "MY_C_NAME"
key                  = "MY_KEY"
```

My backend is in Azure, so if my file is in a backend.tfbackend file, I run

```
terraform init -backend-config=backend.tfbackend
```

I enabled trace logging, and I can see that my file is not getting read as terraform says it cannot be found, but it is definitely there. I spoke to another engineer I work with and he said that this just started to stop working.

Anyone have any idea's on what the issue may be? I don't see how I would specify that that backend should use the azurerm provider when I create the config file, could I be missing that?

My Steps:

- create my file in a key=value format
- run `terraform init -backend-config=<path to file>`

I expect Terraform to init with the info in my config file

Answer (score 0):

Did you log in with `az login`?

Is `terraform` executed next to `tf` files?

Does the command look similar to

```bash
terraform init\
-backend-config="storage_account_name=${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}"\
-backend-config="container_name=${CONTAINER_NAME}"\
-backend-config="access_key=$${ACCOUNT_KEY}"\
-backend-config="key=${TFSTATE_FILE}"
```

Comment: az login, check - that did not help, not sure what yuo mean by is if terraform is executed next to TF files, i have the tfbackend file in the same dir as other TFs, i even tried a subfolder and point to that, i have tried to pass the parms one at a time like you show that that too did not work. I keep seeing this message: Meta.Backend: no config given or present on disk, so returning nil config

Comment: Have you defined a `required_providers` block and added `azure` to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your config shouldn't look like just that.  You need to specify what backend type you're using, etc.

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "YOUR_RG_NAME"
    storage_account_name = "YOUR_SA_NAME"
    container_name       = "YOUR_C_NAME"
    key                  = "YOUR_KEY"
  }
}
```

I usually declare it separately from providers (i.e. `backend.tf`)